# Regex in python for extract informations of request

Tags: python, regex, request

I need extract information of a web page with python , in perl i use this code:

```
if($body =~ /info(.*)info/){
print $1;
}
```

how to convert this code for python ?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import re

body = '' # your text here

for m in re.findall('info(.*)info', body):
    print m
```

Read more about `re` in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)